# Using a pointer-to-pointer to access a pointer-to-pointer in a structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer to a pointer to a structure and I am trying to access a pointer-to-pointer pointer within that structure.  I keep getting an error that reads: "request for member 'buckets' in something not a structure or union."  I commented next to the error.  So my question is, how do I properly access buckets and allocate memory for it.

```
typedef struct bucket {
  char *key;
  void *value;
  struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
  int key_count;
  int table_size;
  void (*free_value)(void *);
  Bucket **buckets;
} 


int create_table(Table ** table, int table_size, void (*free_value)(void *)){
  int iterate = 0;
  *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));

  if(table && table_size != 0) {
    (*table)->key_count = 0;
    (*table)->table_size = table_size;
    (*table)->free_value = free_value;
    (*table)->buckets = malloc(table_size * sizeof(Bucket));  /* Error is here */

    while(iterate < table_size)
      *table->buckets[iterate++] = NULL;
    return SUCC;
  }
  return FAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of your allocation:

```
(*table)->buckets = malloc(table_size * sizeof(Bucket));
```

It looks as though you are attempting to create space for table_size buckets and not table_size pointers to bucket. It the allocation should read:

```
(*table)->buckets = malloc(table_size * sizeof(Bucket*));
```

The error, I believe, is further down in the while loop. Operator -> has precedence over [] which has precedence over *, therefore you are actually saying *(table->buckets[iterate++]), and table is a pointer-pointer and does therefore not have a member called bucket.

Comment: Note, the malloc error could have been avoided by using the idiom `ptr = malloc( N * sizeof *ptr );`

Answer (score 1):

(Note: You're missing a `Table;` in your second `typedef`.

> ```
> int create_table(Table ** table, int table_size, void (*free_value)(void *)){
>   int iterate = 0;
>   *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));
>
>   if(table && table_size != 0) {
> ```

This isn't right. You should test `table` **before** you allocate memory, and then test `*table`.

> ```
>     (*table)->key_count = 0;
>     (*table)->table_size = table_size;
>     (*table)->free_value = free_value;
>     (*table)->buckets = malloc(table_size * sizeof(Bucket));  /* Error is here */
> ```

Here, you are allocating space for `table_size` number of `Bucket`, but assigning the memory to a pointer to pointer to `Bucket`. It looks like you want to allocate `table_size` number of **pointers** to `Bucket`.

> ```
>     while(iterate < table_size)
>       *table->buckets[iterate++] = NULL;
> ```

This is the same as `*(table->buckets[iterate++])` which is obviously wrong. `table` is not a pointer to struct, `*table` is. This is where your real error is.

---

I would probably write something like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int key_count;
  int table_size;
  void (*free_value)(void *);
  Bucket **buckets;
} Table;

int create_table(Table **table, int table_size, void (*free_value)(void *))
{
  if (!table || table_size == 0) {
    return FAIL;
  }
  *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));
  if (*table) {
    (*table)->key_count = 0;
    (*table)->table_size = table_size;
    (*table)->free_value = free_value;
    (*table)->buckets = malloc(table_size * sizeof(Bucket *));
    if ((*table)->buckets) {
      int iterate = 0;
      while(iterate < table_size)
        (*table)->buckets[iterate++] = NULL;
      return SUCC;
    }
  }

  if (*table) {
    free ((*table)->buckets);
  }
  free (*table);
  return FAIL;
}
```